# Storing Array of values into wordpress options

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, jquery

I'm trying to implement an option page on wordpress, when user clicks on a button a row will be appended to a table, but I just can't seem to get these added row into wordpress options, and saving these values when the user clicks save the options:
here's my code.

```
$('input.formType').on('click', function(){
    var myvalue = $(this).val();
    $('.append').append('<tr><td class="row-title">'+myvalue+'</td><td><button class="button button-primary">Delete</button></td></tr>');


});
```

Html:

```
<input type="button"  value="myvalue1" class="formType button button-default">
<input type="button"  value="myvalue2" class="formType button button-default">
```

The problem is that I want to store array of these values into wordpress options.

Comment: A few questions:
1) Where is the HTML for the element with a class of `append`?
2) For each value added you want that value to be added to an array and then stored in the options?

Comment: It's a table with class of append these html elements get appended once the user clicks the button, and yes I want for each value added to be stored in wordpress option as an array